# How are Azure isSoftDelete false/true values determined?

Tags: azure, scim

When deprovisioning users, we are referencing `isSoftDelete` to `active` in our attribute mapping. When using the following in the mapping, and then removing a user from the group, it isn't deactivating in the SaaS platform.

```
Switch([isSoftDeleted], "false", "true", "true", "false")
```

How do we determine what values to put after `isSoftDeleted`? Should we be using the following?

```
Switch([isSoftDeleted], "false", "1", "true", "0")
```

Does capitalization matter on the true/false values?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title:

IsSoftDeleted returns true when one or more of the following conditions is met:

1. User is disabled in Azure AD (accountEnabled = False)
2. User is soft-deleted in Azure AD
3. User was previously assigned to application and is unassigned, AND provisioning is set to "Sync assigned users and groups"
4. User was previously in scope based on scoping filters set on the User attribute mapping section and now is not in scope

To answer the question of "What values do we provide" - that depends on what standard/API is being used. If it's SCIM 2.0, it would be "True" and "False", case insensitive, but if it's some other proprietary API from one of our gallery app integrations it could be different. For anything directly from the gallery (rather than a non-gallery app), it's best to stick with the default configuration. If it's a non-gallery app, that only works with SCIM 2.0 and the default configuration should also be acceptable.

As to why users aren't being deactivated in your specific case, that's something that will likely need involvement either from the support team of the SaaS platform, Microsoft, or both. Someone from either Microsoft or the SaaS platform needs to determine what was actually sent from AAD -> SaaS vendor, and at that point it's likely either a question of "Why didn't AAD send any request", "Why didn't AAD send the correct request", or "Why didn't the SaaS vendor respond as expected to the seemingly correct request that AAD sent"?